# Phonegap screen jumps with checkbox and hidden div

Tags: cordova, checkbox, scroll, focus

I'm using phonegap 2.3.0 to build a form, in my form I jave a couple check boxes that when clicked open a hidden div. The problem is that the screen either jumps to the top of the page or to the last input that had focus. I have tried to add focus to the input in the hidden div onclicking the checkbox, it did not work. I have tried to add blur to the entire form, that did not work. here is what I have...I am not sure what to do, I do not want to use a dropdown list for a simple yes/no but I tested and it works without fail....

```
input  data-theme="b" type="checkbox" name="parking_issuesC" id="parking_issuesC" onclick="fnchecked(this.checked,'67');document.getElementById('parking_issues').focus();"  /> <b><font color="#cc0033">* &nbsp;</font> Parking Issues?</b> </label>


            <div style="display:none;" id="select67" name="select67" valign="top">
            <label for="ladder_size"><b><font color="#cc0033">EXPLIAN</font></b></label>
            <input type="text" name="parking_issues" value="" id="parking_issues">
            <hr></div>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the jquery-mobile framework?

Comment: Yes, I take it there is a bug or that I should not be??

Comment: i tihnk you should use .show() and .hide() with jquery mobile

Comment: worked like a champ, Thanks!

Comment: ok i created it as the answer, dont forget to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after further testing scrollTo was used, show and hide work with select menus but not with check boxes. Jquery needs to work on their platform a little more IMO.

Answer (score 0):

use .show() and .hide() with jquery mobile

Comment: well done! I would rate this answer but have no feedback so all you get is a :thumbsup: lol thanks